# querySetCell to NULL when copying data?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

So here is my situation.

I have to work with some legacy code. This code gives me a query object back that I must append some rows to. Basically, I need to duplicate 1 row N times (N is not a constant) and then manually adjust some data.

Now, at least IMO what I'm doing really is not the right way to do things. I would much rather return a query object that needs no modifications on the CF side and generates the proper dataset on the database. But alas, I have no access to the original query :(

So here's my crack at. I decided to write a generic function that duplicates a query row, and then I can manually set whatever cells I need once I have the copy appended.

Please see below:

```
private function duplicateQueryRow(
    required query originalQuery,
    required numeric rowNum
) {
    queryAddRow(arguments.originalQuery, 1);
    for (local.i = 1; local.i LTE listLen(originalQuery.columnList); local.i += 1) {
        columnName = listGetAt(originalQuery.columnlist, i);
        querySetCell(originalQuery, columnName, originalQuery[columnName][rowNum], originalQuery.recordcount);
    }
}
```

The problem:

Suppose some of the columns are NULL. 
For example, suppose the value of column ACOLUMN is NULL at row 5.
When I do this, the last row's ACOLUMN value will be "" due to CF not handling NULLs. Now if I do a `select distinct ACOLUMN from QUERY_NAME` I'll get row 5 AND the latest row since `NULL <> [empty string]`.

I did have a solution and it's below:

```
private function duplicateQueryRow(
    required query originalQuery,
    required numeric rowNum
) {
    queryAddRow(arguments.originalQuery, 1);
    for (local.i = 1; local.i LTE listLen(originalQuery.columnList); local.i += 1) {
        columnName = listGetAt(originalQuery.columnlist, i);           
        if (originalQuery[columnName][rowNum] NEQ "") {
            querySetCell(originalQuery, columnName, originalQuery[columnName][rowNum], originalQuery.recordcount);
        }
    }
}
```

That works, for now since NULLs will not be copied, but I just dont have confidence that this is correct....

Was wondering if someone had a better solution? Or at the least see if something might be problematic with this function. The requirement I suppose is for a function that given a query and a rowNumber to copy will return the query with a copy of query's rowNumber row at the end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Or at the least see if something might be problematic with this
>   function.

The obvious issue that comes to mind is that it does not differentiate between actual empty strings and nulls. So columns that contain actual empty strings would be considered `null` according to that logic.

I took a look around and unfortunately could not find any built in functions for this scenario. I thought [`IsNull`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-3c4c0bb81223f1daffb-8000.html) might do it, but it does not seem to handle query columns the way you might expect. If you pass in a query column:

```
        isNull( queryName["columnName"][ rowNumber ] )
```

.. it always returns "NO". Most likely because the query reference evaluates to an empty string, instead of the real value ie `null`.

However, you might be able to use a little *undocumented* functionality. (I would not normally recommend it, but in this case I do not see any alternatives).  CF query objects have an internal method called `getField(rowIndex, columnIndex)` that returns the underlying query value. If you use that value, instead of the one obtained using associative array notation, it should preserve the nulls.

```
   targetRow = queryAddRow(originalQuery, 1);
   columnNames = originalQuery.getColumnList();

   // note: colIndex refers to the position within the original SQL
   for (colIndex = 1; colIndex <= arrayLen(columnNames); colIndex++) {
      realValue = originalQuery.getField( sourceRow, columnIndex );
      originalQuery[ columnNames[colIndex] ][ targetRow ] = realValue;
   }
```

Comment: Right now I'm inclined to go with this recommendation. Because the functionality is undocumented I might wait a bit to see if anyone else chimes in. If not, I'll mark this as the answer. Ok, going to give it a shot right now :) Thanks!

Comment: *I might wait a bit* Please do. Personally I prefer documented methods, but was not able to find one. Hopefully someone else knows a trick I missed :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to modify your original SQL with case statements around the columns you are concerned with to return a string of 'NULL' (or desired) if the column value is null?

Example

```
SELECT column1, 
CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE column2 END as column2,
CASE WHEN column3 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE column3 END as column3
FROM table WHERE...
```

Or if you wanted to kill 2 birds with one stone you could do for null and empty strings like:

```
SELECT column1, 
CASE WHEN NULLIF(column2,'') IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE column2 END as column2,
CASE WHEN NULLIF(column3,'') IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE column3 END as column3
FROM table WHERE...
```

Please note that you can change the 'NULL' value to anything you like and then test against that value (e.g. '[omit]' or '[scrub]').

Hope that helps.

Good Luck.